# How to send a string to report (*.rdlc)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, reporting-services

I have a report in my project and I want to send a string value to it. I host a Report inside a WPF application and run it as a LocalReport.

These are what I have done:

1. Send a ReportParameter. The result is runtime IOException.
2. Create a class with a property name Value and use it on the report. The result is failed at runtime, class must implement IEnumerable, ReportSource, or Type.
3. Create a class that inherited from IEnumerable and add a property name Value. The result is no runtime error but no value show on the report. The value send to the report correctly though.
4. Same as step 3. but inherited from ReportSource (I am not sure about the class name) but the result is same as in 3.

Please let me know if there is anyway I can do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using your original class with the Value property and pass it in as a single member of a list.

```
var val = new ClassWithValueProperty { Value = "StringForReport" };
return new List<ClassWithValueProperty> { val };
```

This has worked for me when I wanted to show the values from a single object on a report.

Comment: How to send it to the report? A report parameter or a report datasource?

Comment: Now, I figure it out. I need to add the class I created to the report (as a DataSet.) Then I have to create a list and you suggest and add the object of the class I created to the list. Finally, I can send the list object to the report and IT WORKS!

Comment: Yeah exactly - it should be as a DataSet